# Simple multi tier accordion list with jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, html-lists

I am trying to simplify a navigation tree with a jquery accordion style menu. With some help from other posts i feel like im missing something simple. What is getting me is that one category has a second sub list. I cant get it to to open.close correctly. the sample code I have here just does not expand "T1 sub b" item. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/9uvgs/203/

html:

```
    <ul class='menu'>
  <li>Tier1</li>
  <ul>
     <li>T1 sub a</li>
     <li>T1 sub b</li>
         <ul>
           <li>T1 sub i</li>
         </ul> 
  </ul>
  <li>Tier 2</li>
  <ul>
      <li>T2 sub a</li>
      <li>T2 sub a</li>
      <li>T2 sub a</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.menu ul').hide();
$('ul.menu>li').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only applying the click event to the direct children of `ul.menu` a simple solution would be to change you selector to `ul.menu li` instead of `ul.menu>li`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.menu ul').hide();
    $('ul.menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.menu ul').hide();
    $('ul.menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();

    });
});
```

I've done this and it looks like working just fine.